# Repeated Local Notifications In Background (Pomodoro Timer)

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, local, uilocalnotification

I am trying to create a Pomodoro timer for iOS, but am having trouble implementing background notifications. Unfortunately, even though my code for firing notifications in the background based on the time left in the current timer seems correct, this code is never executed in the background, so only one local notification is ever fired.

The timer switches type and duration repeatedly after the previous one finishes:

```
func countdown() { // gets called by timer every second
        self.timeRemaining = timeRemaining - 1 // decrement timeRemaining integer
        self.updateTimer()
        if self.timeRemaining == 0 {
            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
        }
        if self.timeRemaining < 0 {
            self.switchTimerType()
            setupLocalNotifications()
        }
        print("counting down")
    }



func switchTimerType() {
    if self.timerType == TimerType.Work {
        self.timerType = TimerType.Break
        self.typeName = "Break"
    }
    else if self.timerType == TimerType.Break {
        self.timerType = TimerType.Work
        self.typeName = "Work"
    }
    setTimeBasedOnTimerType(self.timerType)
    resetTimer()
}


func setTimeBasedOnTimerType(timerType: TimerType) {
        switch timerType {
        case TimerType.Work:
            self.timeMax = Double(self.workTimeMax)
            self.typeName = "Work"

        case TimerType.Break:
            self.timeMax = Double(self.breakTimeMax)
            self.typeName = "Break"
        }
    }
```

Setting up the local notification for the current timer duration (doesn't get called multiple times as intended):

```
func setupLocalNotifications() {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
        self.localNotification = UILocalNotification()
        self.localNotificationEndDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(self.timeRemaining)
        print("Current date: \(NSDate())")
        let alertBody = "Time for " + self.typeName + " is up!"
        let alertTitle = ""
        self.localNotification!.fireDate = self.localNotificationEndDate
        self.localNotification!.alertBody = alertBody
        self.localNotification!.alertTitle = alertTitle
        self.localNotification!.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        self.localNotification!.category = "START_CATEGORY"

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(self.localNotification!)
}
```

Comment: iOS app are paused when in the background and don't execute any code. So any notifications scheduled before your app is sent to the background will fire, but then your app just stops, none of your logic is ever executed so no more notifications are scheduled.

Comment: If you're just starting iOS development you should really start by reading some basic documentation. Here is the section that talks about execution states : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3

Comment: I realize that the iOS app cannot execute code in the background, which is why I am looking for a way to still implement this feature of background notifications for my timer.  Any ideas?

Comment: You have to schedule multiple,notifications before you go to the background.

Comment: @Paulw11 This was my thought. If the work duration is 20 minutes and the break duration is 5 minutes, then create a bunch of local notifications for these intervals. However, things start to get inefficient when the user pauses the timer and I have reschedule a bunch more local notifications when the timer is unpaused. Is this the only way?

Comment: Yes. You either schedule local multiple local notifications; you only need to do this as the app transitions to the background, or you use a server to push notifications